# movq causing Triple Fault

Tags: assembly

I am trying to boot a homegrown kernel. I have successfully shifted the processor into long mode, but then QEMU reports a triple fault on the following instruction:

`movq %rax, ___stack_chk_guard(%rip)`

Why would a `movq` cause a triple fault? (Please post any and all theories. I will respond with comments if they don’t apply or if I need more information.)

Comment: Double fault and triple fault exceptions happen if a "regular" exception (for example segmentation fault) happens and you do not have an exception handler interrupt. The actual fault happening on this instruction is not a triple fault but some other fault (for example a segmentation fault).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of the following possibilities:

1. The address is not properly aligned (movq probably requires 64 bit alignment, it depends on your processor settings)
2. The address is not accessible, but I would imagine you know that data is there (especially since you're using %rip)

Comment: Possibly. The `__stack_chk_guard` jazz references a symbol defined in a separate C file in a position-independent method. Would I align the symbol or the value of %rax, and how would I do that? Also, how can I test if the address is accessible?

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. To answer your questions: To align a symbol you use the `.align` or whatever equivalent in your assembler. To know whether it is aligned, if you can look at how things get loaded, then you should be able to see the symbol and its value. Then determine whether the value is a multiple of 1, 2, 4, 8 (our case), 16...